# Realm high energy impact xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

Xcode is showing high energy impact with only single line and my app is heavily bases on realm. And after running the app for a few minute device getting too much heated.

## Below is my pod file

```
 target 'Realmtest' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'RealmSwift'
 end
```

## Below is my AppDelegate file

```
 import UIKit
 import RealmSwift

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    _ = try! Realm() // if I comment this line, energy impact will be zero

    return true
 }

}
```

## Below is the screenshot of my xcode, which shows high energy impact.

[image]

**I want to know what i am doing wrong and correct way to use realm. As my whole app is heavily based on realm its become critical for me to fix this and I really didn't get any solution.**

// ---- Update
I have update the Realm pod and below is the screenshot of my terminal after installation of updated pod.

After updating the pod I am still facing this issue.

[image]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've included and I would expect at times for the Energy Impact to go up (and down). If you look at your average energy impact, its not high at all. You should be using a more current version of the SDK - 5.4.6 is out now so just update the pod to read `pod 'RealmSwift'` and `pod install` to update it.

Comment: @Jay I have updated the pod but still same issue

Comment: Hmm. I just built and iOS App only using Realm in my podfile and am not seeing the same behavior so I am at a loss. Do you have any other code in your project or did it previously have any other pods or frameworks installed? When I run the app it does go to high but doesn't stay there.

Comment: @Jay Yes, it's goes high once and then came back to down this is when I am in fresh project with above single of code. But in my actual project lots of things are developed on top of Realm and this power uses never comes to down. and if comment out all realm calls 
 app runs with Zero energy impact else it remain always on higher side :(